# Video is not playing in the same page on webview?

Tags: android

I have a requirement which I have to play HTML5 video in webview. I Got output using intent but it diverting the page to player. My requirement is to play video in the same page. As per my information video codec for android browser is there from Android 2.3 onwards but it is not working for me. Could anyone help me?
here is my code:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    String html = "<embed src=\"file:///android_asset/" + "Sample.html" + "              \"play=\"true\" loop=\"true\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"> <embed>";
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(url));
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
            else
            {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(url));
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: could you post some sample code.. what your trying actually?